# Writing SQL query with a date range using postgresql and ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am having problem writing a sql statement with the following tables.
I have two tables one is `meter` another one is `meter_info`.
`meter` table has below columns

```
id, name, created_at
```

and `meter_info` has bellow columns

```
id, voltage, meter_id, created_at
```

data is being saved continuously to `meter_info` table. 
I want to write a query that will take a date range and give me exactly one meter info within each date for each of the meter.

so let's say I have three meters in my meter table.

```
 id     name      created_at
 1      meter-a   2017-10-10
 2      meter-b   2017-10-11
```

and in my meter table i have alot of data

```
id    voltage    created_at     meter_id
1      15         2017-10-10      1
2      16         2017-10-10      1
3      14         2017-10-10      2
4      15         2017-10-10      2
5      13         2017-10-11      1
6      11         2017-10-11      1
7      13         2017-10-11      2
8      12         2017-10-11      2
```

Now I want to write a query that will take a date range parameter and out put like bellow(data range is `2017-10-10`to `2017-10-11`)

```
created_at     meter_id     voltage
2017-10-10         1           16
2017-10-10         2           15
2017-10-11         1           11
2017-10-11         2           12
```

so I want the last record of each meter within the date.
I don't know how to write the sql query.
I am using `Postgresql` and `Ruby on Rails`.
Thanks a ton in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use [DISTINCT ON](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#sql-distinct) clause.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (created_at, meter_id) created_at, meter_id, voltage
FROM meter_info
WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2017-10-10' AND '2017-10-11'
ORDER BY created_at, meter_id, id DESC
;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use rails active record you can do it this way:

```
start_date = Date.new 2017, 10, 10
end_date = Date.new 2017, 10, 11
MeterInfo.select("DISTINCT ON (created_at::date, meter_id) * ").where(created_at: start_date..end_date).order("created_at::date, meter_id, id DESC")
```

Note that I'm assuming your 'created_at' column is a datetime and thus need to be converted to a date for grouping using postgresql ::date.